# create AWS resource based on condition or flag in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

In AWS using terraform, have to create a load balancer resource only when the LB does not exist. For this, I can have a variable defined like "lb_exists=true" and based on this "true" value, the resource has to be created otherwise, terraform should skip the LB creation.

To achieve this, I am planning to have depends_on. If "lb_exists=false", then depends_on should be an empty list or set to no resource name.

```
locals {
  lb_exists = "true"
}

resource "aws_lb" "test" {
  name               = var.alb_name
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  #...
}

data "aws_lb" "test" {
  lb_exists = "${local.lb_exists}"
  depends_on    = ["aws_lb.test"]
}
```

What is the right way to achieve this and how? is there any workaround for this. I do not want to recreate the LB if exists in the AWS. Please suggest.

[EDIT]
copying the full code

```
provider "aws" {
  region = var.aws_region
}

resource "aws_lb" "test" {
  count = local.lb_exists == "true" ? 1 : 0
  name               = var.alb_name
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  security_groups    = var.alb_security_groups
  subnets            = var.alb_subnets


  enable_deletion_protection = true

  access_logs {
    #bucket  = aws_s3_bucket.lb_logs.bucket
    bucket = "aws-lab-demo"
    prefix  = "test-lb-logs"
    enabled = false
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = var.env
    Name = var.vpc_id
  }
}

data "aws_lb" "test" {
 # count = local.lb_exists == "true" ? 1 : 0
  arn  = "${aws_lb.test.arn}"
  name = "${aws_lb.test.name}"
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "test" {
  name     = var.alb_name
  port     = 8080
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id   = var.vpc_id
  stickiness {
    type            = "lb_cookie"
    cookie_duration = 1800
    enabled         = false
  }
  health_check {
    healthy_threshold   = 3
    unhealthy_threshold = 10
    timeout             = 5
    interval            = 10
    path                = "/"
    port                = "8081"
  }
}

data "aws_lb_target_group" "test" {
  arn  = "${aws_lb_target_group.test.arn}"
  name = "${aws_lb_target_group.test.name}"
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "front_end" {
  load_balancer_arn = data.aws_lb.test.arn
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"
  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = data.aws_lb_target_group.test.arn
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve it:

1. You can use [count meta argument](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#count-multiple-resource-instances-by-count) to tell `terraform` how many instances of resource or data source should be created. This could be a recommended way for your case.

```
resource "aws_lb" "test" {
  count = local.lb_exists == "true" ? 1 : 0
 ...
}
```

If you use `count`, then `terraform` creates list of resources and you should access them like this: `aws_lb.test[0]`

2. Second option might be to use [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#for_each-multiple-resource-instances-defined-by-a-map-or-set-of-strings). The difference is that if you use this option, you have to provide either `set` or `map` to `for_each`. This approach is useful when you need to control what kind of resources you are creating. For example, if you have something like this:

```
locals {
  load_balancers = ["app1", "app2"]
}

resource "aws_lb" "test" {
  # you can also make it conditional and provide an empty map
  for_each = { for item in local.load_balanecers: item => item }
 ...
}
```

In this case, `terraform` creates a map of resources that can be accessed by the key provided to `for_each`: `aws_lb.test["app1"]`

Comment: the option 1 skips the aws_lb creation. should be an acceptable answer. still, I have to figure out the aws_alb.*.arn. do you know how to pass the arn of the existing lb from variable instead of reading from aws_lb resource or using data?

Comment: pass arn where? to data source?

Comment: yes, I have the data source to get the arn of the lb if created. since skipping the creation of lb, it fails here. 
data "aws_lb" "test" {
  arn  = "${aws_lb.test.arn}"
  name = "${aws_lb.test.name}"
}

Comment: i think, i can use count to skip the data source using count, but I have to use the arn in the following section to listener like below.resource "aws_lb_listener" "front_end" {
  load_balancer_arn = data.aws_lb.test.arn
}. this will fail unless the data from aws_lb or lb_arn from variable has to be made available.

Comment: Do I understand correct that you need either to create Load Balancer or fetch existing Load Balancer via data source?
If so, then yes, you can use `count` to control data source and then just read ARN from the right place, e.g. `local.lb_exists == "true" ? data.data.aws_lb.test[0].arn : aws_lb.test[0].arn`

Comment: i need to create the load balancer if there is no load balancer that exists and using flags to show that lb exists or not.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand what you mean. If you add `count` to `aws_lb` resource you can control when to create (e.g. if it's not exist) based on the variable value.

Comment: you are right, probably i want to silence the use of aws_lb variables in the rest of the code and test it. thanks and will post if I make any progress on this.